# sqldatasource update() not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, sqldatasource

I am using sqldatasource to perform an update.

I have a Transactions table which stores individual items that the user selects for purchase (item name, item price, orderID, etc)

I have an Orders table which stores values for the Order (account name, order total, etc)

Here is my SqlDataSource as defined in the .aspx page:

```
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:NH_SWAGConnectionString %>" 

        InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [tblOrders] ([OrderDate], [OrderTotal], [OrderAccount], [OrderCostCentre]) VALUES (@OrderDate, @OrderTotal, @OrderAccount, @OrderCostCentre); SELECT @OrderNewID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()" 
        SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [tblOrders]" 
        UpdateCommand="UPDATE [tblOrders] SET [OrderDate] = @OrderDate, [OrderTotal] = @OrderTotal, [OrderAccount] = @OrderAccount, [OrderCostCentre] = @OrderCostCentre WHERE [OrderID] = @original_OrderID AND [OrderDate] = @original_OrderDate AND [OrderTotal] = @original_OrderTotal AND [OrderAccount] = @original_OrderAccount AND [OrderCostCentre] = @original_OrderCostCentre" 
        OldValuesParameterFormatString="original_{0}" 

        oninserting="SqlDataSource2_Inserting"
        oninserted="SqlDataSource2_Inserted" onupdated="SqlDataSource2_Updated" 
        onupdating="SqlDataSource2_Updating">

        <InsertParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Direction="Output" Name="OrderNewId" Type="Int32" />
        </InsertParameters>
        <UpdateParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="OrderDate" Type="DateTime" />                                
            <asp:Parameter Name="OrderAccount" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="OrderCostCentre" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_OrderID" Type="Int32" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_OrderDate" Type="DateTime" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_OrderTotal" Type="Decimal" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_OrderAccount" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_OrderCostCentre" Type="String" />
            <%--<asp:ControlParameter ControlID="lblOrderTotal" Name="OrderTotal" 
                PropertyName="Text" />--%>
        </UpdateParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

You can see I blocked out the code that attaches the OrderID to a Textbox.  I did this because that portion wasn't working.  I then tried to modify the Parameter in Code-Behind:

```
        //Update Order Table with Total of Order
    //SqlDataSource2.UpdateParameters["OrderTotal"].DefaultValue = (string)OrderTotal.ToString();        
    SqlDataSource2.UpdateParameters.Add("OrderTotal", (string)OrderTotal.ToString());
    SqlDataSource2.Update();
```

The page doesn't error out, but the Update to OrderTotal in the Orders Db doesn't update.  It stays at '0'.  Can anyone shed some light on this for me?  I've been trying for 2 days now.  And yes, this is the last time I will be using SqlDataSource - It seems everyone recommends a different approach (DAC?) - Next project I will follow everyone's suggestion :)

Thanks all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, well not sure why it wouldn't automatically update, but I just set the updatecommand before updating manually, and that seemed to have worked:

```
SqlDataSource2.UpdateCommand = "UPDATE tblOrders SET [OrderTotal] = " + (string)OrderTotal.ToString() + " WHERE OrderID = " + OrderNewID;
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
protected void SqlDataSource2_Updating(object sender, SqlDataSourceCommandEventArgs e)
{
    e.Command.Parameters[0].Value = OrderTotal;
    e.Command.Parameters[1].Value = OrderNewId;
}
```

It has been worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Add the OrderTotal to the list of parameters, and then do in code before the update:

```
SqlDataSource2.UpdateParameters["OrderTotal"].DefaultValue = OrderTotal.ToString();
SqlDataSource2.Update();
```

Using the DefaultValue property passes this value to the query.

Or, tap into the Updating event, and add the new value to the event argument collection of values.  This gets passed to the backend.

HTH.

Comment: I tried that before (see my commented-out code above) but I tried it again: 

//Update Order Table with Total of Order 

SqlDataSource2.UpdateParameters.Add("OrderTotal", (string)OrderTotal.ToString()); 

SqlDataSource2.UpdateParameters["OrderTotal"].DefaultValue = (string)OrderTotal.ToString(); SqlDataSource2.Update(); 

...doesn't update the value :(

Comment: Also tried adding the parameter to the aspx file and still doesn't update: <asp:Parameter Name="OrderTotal" Type="Decimal" />

Comment: OK, updated my post above.  You could also try the Updating event, passing the value through the event arg.

Comment: I still haven't figured this out.  What would the Table's column type have to be in SQL Server for this to work?  Do you have a way that I can track the @originalOrderID and @OrderTotal parameter's value before the update occurs?